# Mootools trying to parse identifier jQuery

Tags: jquery, mootools, conflict

I know it's a bad idea to mix frameworks but it's not my choice.  I had to implement a jquery date picker for one field.  The site uses mootools.  The problem is I need to open a page in a smoothbox overlay, and this page has a jquery date picker.  I get an error where mootools tries to parse the jQuery identifier.  Is there a way to get mootools to ignore the string jQuery?

```
<input type="text" id="selDate" name="selDate" placeholder="Date" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/ui-  lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>      
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#selDate" ).datepicker();
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Mootools parses jQuery and gives an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I've tried wrapping jquery without no conflict in an anonymous function but I still get that error.

Comment: Where exactly do you think that MooTools is trying to parse jQuery? It looks like this problem has nothing to do with MooTools. If I had you guess, you don't have the jQuery JS file in your page.

Comment: No jQuery lib and ui lib is being called right before the script.  And when the error shows in chrome developer tools, it gives the file name where the exception is caught - mootools-core-1.26-yc

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please.

Comment: Mootools and jQuery can work together. I don't see any Mootools in your code, and the reason you point out doesn't make sense to me. Do you have live link to the problem, or a jsfiddle?

Comment: the only time this would come as a mootools error is if you inject the above snippet into your page after a mootools ajax call with `evalResponse: true, evalScripts: true` because it won't do the script injection on time before trying to evaluate the jQuery expression. since you use smoothbox, I assume it intercepts a link and outputs the response? still - the intent of adding jQuery and jQuery UI for the sake of a simple datepicker? google `mootools Arian datepicker`

Answer (score -2):

whoa whoa no need for the downvote fellas!

maybe this can help? **HTML elements have [onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) events**

which can be demonstrated [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_onload) and should work on script load as well

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function yourFunctionName()
    {
        //jQuery functionality works here
    }
</script>

...
```

make sure your script inclusion of jquery has the **onload** property:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" onload="yourFunctionName()" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: yes there is a need for downvoting, don't want people to pick up wrong answers as a pattern when they find this later on. he is injecting HTML with script tags into his modal after XHR, which needs special work, mootools won't do it automatically and scripts won't load. `onload=` on a script is a bad practice at the best of times, event handlers on elements is a very bad practice, load event on script els is also broken in old IE where you need to hook into `readystatechange` instead. `onload=` attr after `innerHTML` update never fires. __"should work"__?